# Check docker instance in Bash

Tags: docker, awk

Having `docker ps -a`

I want to match the `NAMES` `VERSION` and `STATUS`.

```
docker ps -a --format "{{.Image}}\t{{.Status}}" | awk -F$"\t" '{printf "%s|%s\n", $1, $2}'
```

***Output:***

```
registry.com/project/glass/glass_front:2.2.15.4|Up 6 days
registry.com/project/glass/glass_proxy:2.2.15.4|Up 6 days
registry.com/project/glass/glass_modeles_front:2.1.5.2|Up 6 days
```

How can i modify my command to have this:

```
glass_front | 2.2.15.4 | Up 6 days
glass_proxy | 2.2.15.4 | Up 6 days
glass_modeles_front| 2.1.5.2 | Up 6 days
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using colon as the separator in the docker ps command, then use sed to  transform the colon to pipe and remove the prefix:

```sh
docker ps -a --format "{{.Image}}:{{.Status}}" \
| sed -e 's/:/ | /g' -e 's,^.*/,,'
```

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following, not tested it as don't have `docker` command. Its based on completely shown sample output of OP only.

```
docker ps -a --format "{{.Image}}\t{{.Status}}" \  
| awk -F'\t'  '{num=split($1,arr,"[/:]");print arr[num-1],arr[num],$2}'
```

***OR(only using field separator capability of `awk`)***

```
docker ps -a --format "{{.Image}}\t{{.Status}}" \ 
 | awk -F"[/:\t]" '{print $4,$5,$NF}'
```

***Explanation(1st solution):*** Running `docker` program(what OP shown) then passing its output as an input to `awk` command. In `awk` command setting field separator as TAB. Then splitting 1st field into an array(arr) with delimiter of `/`,`:`, then finally printing arr's 2nd last and last items here with 2nd field of current line.

Comment: the first proposal is more general and do not make assumption on the number of elements in the paths, the second supposes it is a/b/c/d